# Programm that tracks changes on web page

Tags: javascript, web

I have a web page that has several images on it and a script in it which changes picture of one random image once in some time interval. Script changes the image by rewtiting its file in the cash an updating it on the page. So url of the image picture doesnt chage in html code:

```
socket.on("banner", function(info) {
    banName = "banner" + info.bid;
    ban = document.getElementById(banName).getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + info.image;
    img.onload = function(){ban.drawImage(img, 0, 0);};
});
```

How can I track image change using for example C#, when the page is in the browser?

Comment: May I ask what kind of desktop program do you have in mind?

Comment: For expamle c# program that saves the image updated on the page

Comment: Can I see an example of this web page? So I can see how the 'rewriting its file in the cash' works

Comment: By tracking, do you mean only to have changes detected or do you want save all the images?

Comment: Save one that has changed,
Thats not important, I just wonder how to access the web page that is currently in browser (for ex Firefox) from C# code

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, retrieve the image periodically and load it into a byte array.  Checking changes is just a matter of checking if the byte array has changed.

edit:

It seems the hard part is about how can one retrieve the image data.  Without any javascript code in the browser, use C# to establish a websocket connection to mimic the behavior of javascript.

But I think it would be easier done by modifying the javascript code in the browser.